# How to enter part of a command automatically, after another command executed?

Tags: command-line, history, functions

I want to create a function for grep-ing my command line history by `history | grep {keyword}`. And after seeing the list and choosing the command by line number ,I want to execute it by `!{line_number}` .

Because in the next command I always will use `!` ,I want it to be typed automatically and wait for me to enter the line number.
How should I do this

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866005/bash-how-to-prefill-command-line-input

Answer (score 1):

If like me you have set a `HISTSIZE` value to 10000+, the output of the `grep` command could be quite large to parse.

Instead I would suggest to use the `reverse-i-search` and `i-search` bash features:

> `reverse-search-history` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>)
>
> Search backward starting at the current line and moving ‘up’ through the history as necessary. This is an incremental search.
>
> `forward-search-history` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>)
>
> Search forward starting at the current line and moving ‘down’ through the the history as necessary. This is an incremental search.

Note that to work properly you may have to disable XON/XOFF flow control, just type: `stty -ixon`

[image]

Source: [Unable to forward search Bash history similarly as with CTRL-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791765/unable-to-forward-search-bash-history-similarly-as-with-ctrl-r/791800#791800)

Comment: I already knew about this, I specifically want that function I described